# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Board & Card Games Stack Exchange](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Playing Cards from Unhinged and Unglued](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14679/playing-cards-from-unhinged-and-unglued)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I tap a creature in response to an instant?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14767/can-i-tap-a-creature-in-response-to-an-instant)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is a card that was played and immediately trashed "in play"?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14956/is-a-card-that-was-played-and-immediately-trashed-in-play)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Draw a card when my deck and my discard piles are empty](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14782/draw-a-card-when-my-deck-and-my-discard-piles-are-empty)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How much replayability can I expect from a core set LCG](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14795/how-much-replayability-can-i-expect-from-a-core-set-lcg)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can you force a player to **Bang** themselves when Dorothy Rage is in play?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14851/can-you-force-a-player-to-bang-themselves-when-dorothy-rage-is-in-play)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Do cards that say "creatures you control" trigger Heroic?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14777/do-cards-that-say-creatures-you-control-trigger-heroic)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Multiple melds for the same card](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14683/multiple-melds-for-the-same-card)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the odds of getting a double run in four-handed pinochle?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14912/what-are-the-odds-of-getting-a-double-run-in-four-handed-pinochle)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Exceeding the monster limit due to an encounter](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14943/exceeding-the-monster-limit-due-to-an-encounter)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

Answer (score 0):

### [Can I tap a creature in response to an instant?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/14767/6352)

I think my *Needs Improvement* was too harsh, but I do think it could've used a quote of *Crypt Sliver*'s ability, even if it was just an example. - SQB.